# D - Handling large numbers of connections

Tags: d

I am trying to implement a TCP server in D. Can anyone tell me how to handle large numbers of incoming connections efficiently in D? Is there an efficient selector mechanism? EPoll ? Something else?

I have the code for opening a standard socket in D. No problem there. It's when I have N connections open and I need to know which ones have data that are ready for reading, and which are ready to have data written to them.

In Java I can use a java.nio.Selector for that. Does D have a similar mechanism?

If yes, does anyone have a code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd use the low-level operating system functions, so socket, epoll, etc on Linux, either overlapped I/O or WSAasyncselect on Windows, etc. `import core.sys.linux.epoll;` to get the epoll definitions, or define them yourself with `extern(C)`.

I'd do it that way because I know that way so it is easy for me, and I'm no fan of libraries anyway. But if you haven't done it that way before you might want to try a lib on for size. This one, for example: https://github.com/etcimon/libasync does a bunch of the cross platform stuff for you. Or there's the vibed.org framework that wraps on top of that libasync for even more abstraction.

Generally speaking, you can do it the same way you do in C, including the same OS calls or the same C libraries too.

As a result, if you find a tutorial for how to do it in C, translating it to D is usually straightforward.

Comment: I will check it out. I think vibe.d is too high level, as we don't need HTTP, WebSockets and all that. Just raw TCP / UDP.

Comment: vibe can do raw tcp/udp too, so you still might want to take a quick look at it.

Comment: Yes, I looked at vibe.d earlier, but I don't want to drag around a whole HTTP / REST stack, DB drivers etc. when I don't need them.

Comment: Really bad argument. - Standard libraries have lots of things you do not need, yet you still use them...

Comment: @DejanLekic That is an equally bad argument. Standard libraries are targeted at much more general purpose functionality than e.g. a REST-based platform.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe libasync looks like a good level of functionality for what I need. Not too much, not too little, focused on a certain set of functionality.

Comment: @JakobJenkov: vibed is, in my view, a general-purpose library because it can be used as solution to many different problems.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the excellent TangoD2 networking API, more specifically Tango Selector(s): https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2/blob/d2port/doc/example/networking/selector.d

Comment: I saw the name "Tango" too while searching for solutions. I will have a look!

Comment: Would suggest not to use this, due to that it has not really been maintained for years.